# How to convert two character ('-' and '_') to JSON format

Tags: regex, json, string, perl, converters

I want to convert below two character ("-" and "_") to JSON format in perl.
To use as JSON. 
But I failed to convert. I want to know how to convert these unique two character.

format

```
'--'    -> ':'
'-_'    -> '{'
'_-'    -> '}'
'__'    -> ','
```

Here is my program

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

sub toJsonFormat {
  my $self = shift;
  my $str = shift;

  $str =~ s/-_/{/g;
  $str =~ s/_-/}/g;
  $str =~ s/--/:/g;
  $str =~ s/__/,/g;                                                                                                          
  return $str;

}
```

This is sample

Try code

```
toJsonFormat('-_service---_key--value_-__-_key--value_-__service---_key--value_-_-')
```

expected

```
"{service:{key:value},{key:value},service:{key:value}}"
```

Got

```
'{service:{key:value_{_{key:value_{_service:{key:value_{-'
```

If you have any idea to convert to expected character, please tell me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about splitting the string and store it in a hash. Then you can `use JSON`. https://metacpan.org/module/JSON

Comment: I don't get it. Your expected output is not valid JSON.

Comment: @innaM  know. Since I can use only "-" and "_", I have no idea to use array.
So after convert, I have to that object put into array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
my %h = (
'--'    => ':',
'-_'    => '{',
'_-'    => '}',
'__'    => ',',
);

my $rx = qr(-_|_-|--|__);

sub toJsonFormat {
  my $str = shift;

  $str =~ s/($rx)/$h{$1}/g;
  return $str;

}

print toJsonFormat('-_service---_key--value_-__-_key--value_-__service---_key--value_-_-')
```

So make a regex from all the keys you're matching and replace with the corresponding values...